# Spring Boot Batch program autowiring not working across multiple configuration files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I created a Spring Boot application with Spring Batch.  To make the code more readable, I split the creation of the Step Beans in separate configuration files.  When I did that I could no longer get the beans instantiated.  I stripped all the code down to the bare essentials ro display the error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field step1 in com.test.autowire.BatchConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.test.autowire.Step1' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.autowire.Step1' in your configuration.
```

I have seen similar posts on Stack overflow, but none of the solutions worked for me.  I moved everything down to the same package.

The error is in the step1 attribute definition in the following class

```
package com.test.autowire;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    Step1 step1;

    @Bean
    public Step step()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The bean is defined in this class

```
package com.test.autowire;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@Configuration
public class Step1
{
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader fileReader() 
        throws Exception
    {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder()
                .name("file-reader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("students.csv"))
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(",")
                .names(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "email", "age" })
                .targetType(Student.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The Application class is

```
package com.test.autowire;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The pom file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.autowired</groupId>
  <artifactId>AutowireTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

If I move the FlatFileItemReader fileReader() bean out of the Step1 configuration class to the BatchConfiguration class, everything works fine.
I seem to be missing something obvious.

Comment: no problem can be found, do you have other configuration or classes defined in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a bean of type `Step1` in order to be able to inject it in your `BatchConfiguration` class. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class Step1Configuration {
    @Bean
    public Step1 step1() {
      // return a bean of type Step1
    }
}
```

> To make the code more readable, I split the creation of the Step Beans in separate configuration files

You can define your steps in a separate configuration file, which is fine, but there is no need to create a new type for each step: `Step1`, `Step2`, etc.

For example, you can have:

```
@Configuration
public class StepsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
      // return a bean of type Step
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
      // return a bean of type Step
    }
}
```

then import this class in your `BatchConfiguration` class and use the `Step` beans to define your jobs.

If you really want one configuration class for each step, then you can of course do it but make sure your step bean is of type `Step` and not `Step1`:

```
@Configuration
public class Step1Configuration {
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
      // return a bean of type Step
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.